# Voice memo only saving part of audio

Tags: ios, bug, data-recovery, voice-memo

I recently conducted a 1h30 interview using voice memo, but when trying to save the file the app froze and did not allow me to press any button. It showed that the interview was 1h30 long, though. I had to close the app, because it was completely frozen for 30 min, and it did only save 17 min of the audio. It was a very important interview, and I was hoping that there was a way I could recover the complete file. I later tested again, with another interview, an the same thing happened - an 1h long interview was reduced to 14 min.

I have already tried using recovery data software but none of them work (they are not even able to scan my phone).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How much free space on the phone? Any idea how much space a 1h30 file needs?

Comment: Try iExplorer to access your iPhone. There's a free trial version, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to duplicate the recording twice in the voice memos app, trim each one to 30 mins (so first 30 mins, 2nd 30 mins, and last 30 mins), then save each one to files. Name them as part 1, 2, & 3 if you don't need to combine them. On the other hand, I recommend [LosslessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) to join them back together on a computer very quickly and simply.

Comment: Or 4 times in 15 mins each since the OP states it becomes 17min